# Is there is a way to apply css descendant combinator in asp.net labels

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

```css
.box
{
     font-family:'Verdana';
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
     width:400px;
     position:absolute;
     padding:40px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     box-shadow:0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
     border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
     font-size:15px;
}
.InputType 
{
    font-family:'Verdana';
    padding:10px 0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    box-shadow:none;
    outline:none;
    border:none;     
    border-bottom:2px solid rgb(44, 128, 35);
}
.Labelll
{
    font-size:25px;
    font-family:'Verdana';
}
.Submit
{
  border:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:rgb(44, 128, 35);
  color:#FFFFFF;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  width:100%;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size:15px;
  font-family:'Verdana';
}
.Message
{
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:'Verdana';

}
a,a:visited,a:active,a:hover
{
   color:rgb(44, 128, 35);
   font-family:'Verdana';
}


<div class="box" >
            <asp:Label ID="Labell" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" CssClass="Labelll"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="UserName" runat="server" Text="Your Name"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextUserName" runat="server" CssClass="InputType"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="EMailId" runat="server" Text="Email Id"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextEMailId" runat="server" CssClass="InputType"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Password" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="InputType"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="InputType"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="SignUp" runat="server" Text="Register" CssClass="Submit"/>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Already registered?" CssClass="Message">
            Already registered
            <a href="../LoginPage/Login.aspx">Login</a>
            </asp:Label>
    </div>
```

I'm learning asp.net technology and after a while I just got stuck up with the css in asp.net.Is there is any way for how to apply descendant combinators for asp.net labels and other css selectors as well as some other css properties are not working for asp.net labels so how can I do that?I have also provided the code snippets.

Comment: Post the code you're having issues with.

Comment: Hi Broots Waymb basically the way we apply the descendant selector in html in asp.net its's not working the same way for asp.net labels.So is there is any other way by which I can apply the descendant selector.

Comment: That's nice to know, but you need to post the code you're having trouble with here. Otherwise your question can be closed. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for your help now I have added the code and  also providing you a link this is how I want my Page to look alike but just because of some css selectors not working in asp.net it's creating a problem.Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKhoo6RSEDU

Comment: @NamrataSanger _"some css selectors not working in asp.net"_ What selectors are you talking about? Can you be more specific? An `asp:Label` just renders as a `<span>` tag

Comment: When I am applying a descendant combinator for the html tag then it works but I don't know how to apply descendant combinator for asp.net labels

Comment: @NamrataSanger Well just give the label a class like you have and write a style against that class. Like this: `.Message a {color: red; }` will color the `<a>` tag red thats a descendant of the label with class `.Message`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @zgood Thanks.The way you applied css for this html tag <a> in the same way I would like to apply   for the asp:Label,asp:TextBox and other asp.net Labels so if I put these tags in place of that <a> it will not work.